# Include automatically generated methods in a java class

Tags: java, methods, include, external

I have a question which I am not sure can be answered.

I have a php script on a server that automatically generates a java method based on table contents in a MySQL Database. The script creates a .java file in which this method is saved.

I then download this method and copy and paste the method into my main java class. I think this is an unnecessary step. Is there a way to include the method in the java class rather than copying and pasting.

I am looking to write a reference to the method.java file at the point in the java class where the method should be copied and pasted.

Something like:

```
    public class ShowAlert {
            public void showAlert(String toast) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("alert = "+externalMethod());
    }

    include(externalMethod.java);

}
```

and then externalMethod.java has

```
public String externalMethod(){
return "hello world";
}
```

I am not sure if this is possible but it would be great if it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "include file" facility in Java. I suggest that you generate this instead:

```
public class GeneratedClass {    
    public static String externalMethod(){
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
GeneratedClass.externalMethod();
```

That way, the handwritten file and the generated file can be completely separate.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your fast response. I will try the above and respond. I will also look at the other suggestions for future. Step 1. review my design patterns lecture notes :)

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider to use something like Java `ScriptEngine` (described in JSR 223). Examples can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/).

There are also LUA integrations for Java.

Answer (score 1):

You would ideally keep generated code and manually written code in separate files. In that way  you wont have to do what you are doing. Use Aasmund's suggestion. That's the right way to go. You might have to restructure your code to allow this, but better now than later.

I would ask you to go the extra mile and use interfaces. Your generated code should implement an interface and your manual code should reference everything using the interface alone. You could have a Factory that returns the instance.

This will allow you to increase your decoupling of manual code and the generated code. I would think that would you are doing is using the DAO (data access object) pattern to a certain extent. The DAO pattern works best, if you keep the generated code separate and access it using interfaces. Using interfaces will allow you to change the implementation of the DAO to something else at runtime - such as to run unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PHP template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) to create your complete java class. Your main class will be your template with a placeholder for the generated method.